# Can't login after AMD catalyst driver installation

Tags: ati, login, vga, catalyst

I have almost successfully installed the ATI Catalyst drivers. But now I can't login in to my main account. I enter my password and press enter, then it goes black and back to login screen. Although when I try to login with guest account, it works perfectly.

I dont want to create new user and move my stuff over there. Is there any painless way to get out of this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue a couple of months ago after installing the Catalyst drivers. Try this:

From the LightDM login screen, hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 to switch into a console. Login with your administrative username and password.

From there, try running the following commands:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Then try to log in again.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Sweet, it worked:)

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it!